# Delete HTML Table and paste it in another portion of the webpage, Is this possible using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a HTML table in a page  `<table id="options_table"></table>`

I want to automatically on page load:

1. DELETE the HTML TABLE TAG from one location in a webpage
2. Paste it at another location below this SPAN tag

```
<span><a href="test">test</a><br /></span>
```

Is this possible in Jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to append it.  First, give the span an ID:

```
<span id="afterMe"><a href="test">test</a><br /></span>
```

Then use the following jQuery snippet:

```
$('#afterMe').after($('#options_table'));
```

Here is a simple example:  http://jsfiddle.net/vAewz/

jQuery will automatically move the node.  No need to call `.detach()`.

Answer (score 0):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vvgLU/

```
$('#my-span').after($('#options_table').detach())
```

[$.detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)
[$.after](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

The examples for both should get you going.

Comment: Sorry i know its basic question how do i..  copy the Jquery code from the example here http://jsfiddle.net/vAewz/ ?

Comment: Read the documentation. `after` appends after a selected element. There is no `move` in the context of jQuery. Elements can be added and removed from the DOM.

Comment: I would also note that while detach is not necessary, I'd probably still use it. A common pattern is  1.) clone/detach. 2.) modify. 3.) attach. Modifying the object while it is still on the DOM has performance impacts.

Answer (score 0):

You asked specifically about JQuery, but *[unsolicited advice alert!]* you don't need to resort to the framework. Instead:

```
<table id="source"> ... </table>
<table id="dest"> ... </table>
```

then something like this:

```
getRefToDiv("dest").innerHTML = getRefToDiv("source").innerHTML;
getRefToDiv("source").innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript">                                        
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#click").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#options_table").appendTo('#target');
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id='options_table'>
<tr>
  <td>Something here</td>
</tr>
</table>
<span id="target"><a id="click" href="test">test</a><br /></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it this way.

If you put a `span` or a `div` tag around the two interchanging spots, then on page load you could just do something like this:

```
<span id="start"><table id="options_table"></table></span>
<span id="finish"></span>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#start').html();
    $('#start').html('');
    $('#finish').html(table);
});
```